# Bootstrap Angular 2: White text in submenu

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

in my Angular2 project I am using this navbar: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/2qgMx

I removed the second nav and transferred some `<link>` and `<script>`-tags into my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">

  <title>Relax mal wieder</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my app-root-html --> please refer `<app-root>Loading...</app-root>` in index.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse animated fadeIn" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav animated fadeIn text16">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span>Pay Something<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu animated flipInX" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>PayOptOne Web</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></span>PayOptTwo Web</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></span>PayOptTree Web</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><b> Login</b> <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <!-- Login -->
                  <div class="social-buttons">
                    <div class="iconSpecial"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>Login</div>
                  </div>
                  <form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="login" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">login</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Entrar Usuário" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Senha</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password" required>
                      <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">Esquecí minha senha ?</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Entrar</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox text-dark">
                      <label>
                                             <input type="checkbox"> Manter-me Logado
                                             </label>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

The code snipped works fine, but for some reason the text in my opened combobox is white so I can't read the text. Only hovering over the subitems makes the text visible.

Problem in chrome and firefox and ie.

Hope you can help me. Thx in advance.

Comment: what is your `style.cs`? may be font color change there

Comment: You made my day, B. Desai. I changed my the `.navbar-default .nav li a {` of my style.css and now it's working. Thank you so much!